# How to best use Large images in training set for deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, image-classification, training, multilabel-classification

I would like to ask you about how I should deal with the images I have. They are really large. They have this shape: **(3000, 4000, 3)**.

I'm working on a ***multilabel classification model***.

And I want to know if it's wise to **slice the images into equal tiles** (using **image_slicer**) and to feed them to the model **as well as resize the original** images to the requisite input size of the model and feed those too.

*So the training set would be: resized_original_images + tiles_of_original_image*

Thank you

Comment: If you were to scale your images down, would you lose a lot of information?

Comment: @NishalHp The resolution isn't great. They're underwater images of algae, seagrass, corals etc. So the quality is bad. I'm planning to do a dehazing enhancement technique to make it better. To answer your question, I'm sure that going from the original size to say 256x256x3 would incur loss of details.